# VueJS show multiple input fields conditionally

Tags: vue.js

I have a 'Add' button which adds a select box and when I select a value in the select box I want to display an input field so every time I click 'Add' it should show a select box and when I select a value in it I would like to display an input field.

I know I could use a flag 'selected' but when I already add one select box this would change the flag to true and show the input field immediately after I click 'Add' but I want the input field to show only when a value is selected.

```
<template>
    <button @click="onBtnClick">Add<button>
    <select>...</select> # This gets added when 'Add' button is clicked
    <input v-if="selected" type="text" /> # This should show when a value is selected.
<select>
</template>

data(){
    return {
       selected: false
  }
},
methods: {
  onValueSelected(){
    this.selected = true
  }
}
```

Do you have any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Comment: how do you calling `onValueSelected` method?

Comment: Right now I am not calling it at all because it won't do what I need. Normally,  I would call it with `@change="onValueSelected"`

Comment: @jedi Do you need the `input` field to be dynamically added also?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. I need the input text field to be dynamic as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for) and push new fields onto the collection at will.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      goods: []
    }
  },

  methods: {
    addSelect() {
      let item = {
        id: this.goods.length,
        menus: [
          { value: '', text: '- select -' },
          { value: 1, text: 'Item 1' },
          { value: 2, text: 'Item 2' },
          { value: 3, text: 'Item 3' }
        ],
        input: {
          show: false
        }
      };

      this.goods.push(item);
    },
    
    showInput(item, e) {
      item.input.show = e.currentTarget.selectedIndex > 0;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="addSelect">Add to cart</button>

  <div v-for="item in goods" :key="item.id" class="goods">
    <select @change="showInput(item, $event)">
      <option 
        v-for="opt in item.menus" 
        :key="opt.key"
        value="opt.value">
        {{opt.text}}
      </option>
    </select>
    
    <input v-if="item.input.show" type="text" value="0" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I would recommend against using the `change` event, and instead use a `v-model` instead. Then simply check in the `v-if` if the modelled value is not a falsy value. (Something similar to https://codesandbox.io/s/y26k62r62v ) Using the change event opens up questions like "But what if I changed the value of the dropdown myself", while using a `v-model` and a `v-if` that uses that model will work correctly regardless of how the modelled data changes.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I am using `v-model` myself in different places, but it's good to note that `v-model` actually [does the same thing](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) as binding the `value` attribute and `@change` or `@input`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I can render a new component and pass it props. Everytime a new component is rendered it gets `selected` flag as `false` by default and I can change it then by selecting a value in the select box.

```
<b-form-group 
    v-if="element.elementName === 'Some value'"
    label="Select field *:"
    label-for="benefitSelectField">
    <SalaryField :element="element" />
</b-form-group>
```

`SalaryField` component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <select @change="onValueSelected" ></select>
    <input v-if="selected" type="text" />       
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      element: Object
    },
    data(){
      return {
        selected: false,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onValueSelected() {
        this.selected = true
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```